# Qt: Wshadow warning on nested foreach

Tags: c++, qt, foreach, compiler-warnings

I enabled the compiler flag "-Wshadow" on a Qt project. Now I get a warning for every nested foreach loop in the project. It seems, that the foreach macro uses an identifier which is duplicated in a nested foreach loop.

Quick example:

```
QStringList listA, listB;
foreach (QString a, listA) {
    foreach (QString b, listB) {
        qDebug() << a << b;
    }
}
```

Compiler output:

```
Test.cpp:46:9: warning: declaration shadows a local variable [-Wshadow]
        foreach (QString b, listB) {
        ^
/usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qglobal.h:911:21: note: expanded from macro 'foreach'
#    define foreach Q_FOREACH
                    ^
/usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qglobal.h:857:47: note: expanded from macro 'Q_FOREACH'
for (QForeachContainer<__typeof__(container)> _container_(container); \
                                              ^
Test.cpp:45:5: note: previous declaration is here
    foreach (QString a, listA) {
    ^
/usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qglobal.h:911:21: note: expanded from macro 'foreach'
#    define foreach Q_FOREACH
                    ^
/usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qglobal.h:857:47: note: expanded from macro 'Q_FOREACH'
for (QForeachContainer<__typeof__(container)> _container_(container); \
                                              ^
```

Is there a way to enable -Wshadow but suppress the warnings from nested foreach?

Comment: The `foreach` macro creates a variable `_container_`, and if you nest another `foreach` macro then you will have two variables with the same name in different scopes, the variable in the inner scope shadowing the variable in the outer scope. Maybe you should try using [range-based `for` loops](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) instead?

Comment: Why not just use `c++11` for for this? Or try `BOOST_FOREACH`. They are both, actually, not such good as `c++11`'s foreach but..

Comment: Have a look at this discussion: http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/nested-BOOST-FOREACH-and-Wshadow-td2657975.html